# Removing from a ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

I am trying to remove certain entries from a `ConcurrentHashMap`. However since this happens in a multithreaded environment, entries may be removed and/or modified while the iteration is in progress. When this happens the `remove` method on the iterator will remove the entry even if it was modified since received through `next`. I have constructed an example program to illustrate this:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

map.put("foo", "bar");
map.put("quz", "qaz");

CountDownLatch foundBar = new CountDownLatch(1);
CountDownLatch doneModifying = new CountDownLatch(1);
CountDownLatch doneIterating = new CountDownLatch(1);

new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, String> entry = it.next();
            if (entry.getValue().equals("bar")) {
                foundBar.countDown();
                doneModifying.await();
                it.remove();
            }
        }
        doneIterating.countDown();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new Error(e);
    }
}).start();

foundBar.await();
map.put("foo", "nob");
doneModifying.countDown();

doneIterating.await();
System.out.println(map);
```

The output will be `{quz=qaz}` and not as I expected `{quz=qaz,foo=nob}`. My question is: How do I achieve the desired behavior? Is the `remove(key, value)` method on the Map during the iteration the right choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should use the two argument `remove` method.  While direct collection mutation during iteration is generally a bad thing for most java collections, ConcurrentHashMap allows this.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I was aware that this was a possibility, just not sure if the most elegant.